# Unicode and Telegram Desktop app

Tags: unicode

Is there any way to enable unicode input in *Telegram Desktop App* for unix/linux systems?

**Addendm**:
The problem seems to be due to some qt-ibus configuration problem according [to this](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/1288) unfortunately they don't say how to work around it.

Comment: This is a question related to the App and not to Linux.

Comment: If the app runs on U&L, it's [in-scope](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). There may or may not be expertise in the app at U&L.

Comment: @RalfFriedl It's linux-desktop app for telegram and apparently the problem is due to some ibus-xim-qt problem, or at least that's what I get googling around. 
Unfortunately I haven't been able to found a solution, just some hint on what could cause the problem.